# Most flexible tool to track arbitrary events in a web app for the purpose of A/B testing?

Tags: rest, web-applications, analytics, ab-testing

I am looking for some tool or service that can be used to track arbitrary events in web based software, for the purpose of running A/B tests and measuring various other things. I am aware of Optimizely, but that seems only suitable for testing simple things in normal websites and Google Analytics is not really suitable for this type of things and there is a lot of hassle when you want to track events from the backend and link them with a user's session in GA.

An ideal solution would be some service accepting HTTP GET requests with arbitrary parameters and then letting users do queries in an SQL-like language. I have many times put together some less scalable solution with MySQL or a less flexible one that stores everything in text files and processed and aggregated them separately into desired format. But building a both flexible and scalable version would require a lot more time and I guess there are already good solutions out there. Does anyone know of any?

Other requirements are:

- It must be possible to do both back-end and front-end requests.
- It must be possible to do use it in widgets, running on other peoples' websites
- It would be nice if it could automatically create readable reports with maybe some diagrams, etc.

If anyone has any experience with this kind of tools, I would be very glad to hear your thoughts.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried mixpanel? We've found it quite flexible and powerful.

- https://mixpanel.com/